# How to iterate and replace JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm pretty new to this json/array, the data below comes from a table, and i need to port it to another table which requires me to sort according to the countries with the highest id...
the Countries loaded in are dynamic...
appreciate if someone can show me how i can group all the countries into "Country" and push to the correct data[i]

```
var data = [
        {"Product": "DESKTOP", "Type": "APPLE" , "CN": "", "IN": "", "SG": "20"},
        {"Product": "DESKTOP", "Type": "DELL" , "CN": "", "IN": "", "SG": "20"},
        {"Product": "LAPTOP", "Type": "XXX", "CN": "", "IN": "90", "SG": "28"},
        {"Product": "MOBILE", "Type": "XXX","CN": "1","IN": "","SG": "28"},
        {"Product": "TABLET", "Type": "XXX","CN": "13","IN": "","SG": "238"}
    ]

what_i_need = [
    {"Product": "DESKTOP",
     "Type": "APPLE",
     "Country": [
        {"country": "CN", "id": ""}
        {"country": "IN", "id": ""}
        {"country": "SG", "id": "20"}
    ]},
    ...
    ...
]
```

i tried doing looping but it ended up like this

```
[{"country": "CN", "id": ""}
{"country": "IN", "id": ""}
{"country": "SG", "id": "20"}
{"country": "CN", "id": ""}
{"country": "IN", "id": ""}
{"country": "SG", "id": "20"}
```

Comment: put your code, to generate the array, and will help you better

Comment: Can you share your code and the attempts?

Comment: while i was trying to generate the array, h77 & Shiladitya posted the answer, thanks so much! i wish i can give shiladitya the tick as well, but h77 got the fastest hand. appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to change the array format.

```js
var data = [{
    "Product": "DESKTOP",
    "Type": "APPLE",
    "CN": "",
    "IN": "",
    "SG": "20"
  },
  {
    "Product": "DESKTOP",
    "Type": "DELL",
    "CN": "",
    "IN": "",
    "SG": "20"
  },
  {
    "Product": "LAPTOP",
    "Type": "XXX",
    "CN": "",
    "IN": "90",
    "SG": "28"
  },
  {
    "Product": "MOBILE",
    "Type": "XXX",
    "CN": "1",
    "IN": "",
    "SG": "28"
  },
  {
    "Product": "TABLET",
    "Type": "XXX",
    "CN": "13",
    "IN": "",
    "SG": "238"
  }
];

var fixedKeys = ["Product", "Type"];
var result = data.map(function(item) {
  var x = {
    Product: item.Product,
    Type: item.Type,
    Country: []
  };
  for (var country in item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty(country) && !fixedKeys.includes(country))
      x.Country.push({
        country: country,
        id: item[country]
      });
  }
  return x;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for much! you saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/sdhaojsp/

```js
var data = [
        {"Product": "DESKTOP", "Type": "APPLE" , "CN": "", "IN": "", "SG": "20"},
        {"Product": "DESKTOP", "Type": "DELL" , "CN": "", "IN": "", "SG": "20"},
        {"Product": "LAPTOP", "Type": "XXX", "CN": "", "IN": "90", "SG": "28"},
        {"Product": "MOBILE", "Type": "XXX","CN": "1","IN": "","SG": "28"},
        {"Product": "TABLET", "Type": "XXX","CN": "13","IN": "","SG": "238"}
    ];
  var outputData = [];  
$.each(data, function(i){
 var temp = {};
  var tempCountry = {};
 $.each(data[i], function(key){
   if(key === "Product" || key === "Type"){
     temp[key] = data[i][key];
    }else{
     tempCountry["country"] = key;
      tempCountry["id"] = data[i][key];
      if(typeof temp["Country"] === 'undefined') {
       temp["Country"] = [];
      }
       temp["Country"].push(tempCountry);
        tempCountry = {};
    }
  });
  outputData.push(temp);
});

console.log(outputData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for much! you saved my life!

Comment: thank you! ill upvote your answer once i have enough rep! thanks for the help